# Cannot get the JSON data from service method getNutrition() through post request to Nutritionix API. New to using api and angular

Tags: angular, typescript

> Trying to call the service and **this.food** is a string

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ClientService } from '../../services/client.service';
import { Client } from '../../models/Client';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute, Params } from '@angular/router';
import { FlashMessagesService } from 'angular2-flash-messages';
import { Route } from '@angular/compiler/src/core';
import { Foods } from '../../models/Foods';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-client-info',
  templateUrl: './client-info.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./client-info.component.css'],
})
export class ClientInfoComponent implements OnInit {
  id: string;
  client: Client;
  food: string;
  foods: Foods;

  constructor(
    private clientservice: ClientService,
    private router: Router,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private flashmessage: FlashMessagesService
  ) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.id = this.route.snapshot.params['id'];
    this.food = this.route.snapshot.params['food'];
    this.clientservice.getClient(this.id).subscribe((client) => {
      this.client = client;
    });
    this.clientservice
      .getNutrition(this.food)
      .subscribe((foods) => (this.foods = foods.foods));
  }
}
```

Trying to get the "foods" from the json in the getNutrition function but not too sure how or if I am doing it correctly. Also its giving me http request errors. I tested it on postman and everything works but the body i send on postman is json so maybe thats the error?

> this is the service below

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {
  AngularFirestore,
  AngularFirestoreCollection,
  AngularFirestoreDocument,
} from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Client } from '../models/Client';
import { map, catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { ThrowStmt } from '@angular/compiler';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class ClientService {
  clientCollections: AngularFirestoreCollection<Client>;
  clientDoc: AngularFirestoreDocument<Client>;
  clients: Observable<Client[]>;
  client: Observable<Client>;
  foods: Observable<any>;
  constructor(private firestore: AngularFirestore, private http: HttpClient) {
    this.clientCollections = firestore.collection('clients');
  }

  getNutrition(query: string): Observable<any> {
    let url: string = 'https://trackapi.nutritionix.com/v2/natural/nutrients';
    let headers = new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'x-app-id': 'xxx',
      'x-app-key': 'xxx',
    });
    let options = { headers: headers };
    this.foods = this.http.post(url, query, options).pipe(
      map((req) => {
        console.log(req);
      })
    );
    return this.foods;
  }
}
```

**this is the json gotten from postman**

```
{
    "foods": [
        {
            "food_name": "apple",
            "brand_name": null,
            "serving_qty": 1,
            "serving_unit": "medium (3\" dia)",
            "serving_weight_grams": 182,
            "nf_calories": 94.64,
            "nf_total_fat": 0.31,
            "nf_saturated_fat": 0.05,
            "nf_cholesterol": 0,
            "nf_sodium": 1.82,
            "nf_total_carbohydrate": 25.13,
            "nf_dietary_fiber": 4.37,
            "nf_sugars": 18.91,
            "nf_protein": 0.47,
            "nf_potassium": 194.74,
            "nf_p": 20.02,
            "full_nutrients": [
               ...
             ]
             ...
    ]
}
```

**EDIT: this is my Food.ts in my models**

```
export interface Foods {
  nf_total_fat?: number;
  nf_saturated_fat?: number;
  nf_cholesterol?: number;
  nf_sodium?: number;
  nf_total_carbohydrate?: number;
  nf_dietary_fiber?: number;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue because you don't return response in map. also you add `req` argument to map instead of `res` because this operator map response not request.

```
this.foods = this.http.post(url, query, options).pipe(
  map((res) => {
    console.log(res);
    return res; 
  })
);
```

---

This is anther issue because you are send body as string instead of object. so you should replace `this.http.post(url, query, options)` with `this.http.post(url, { query }, options)`.

```
getNutrition(query: string): Observable<any> {
    let url: string = 'https://trackapi.nutritionix.com/v2/natural/nutrients';
    let headers = new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'x-app-id': 'xxx',
      'x-app-key': 'xxx',
    });
    let options = { headers: headers };
    this.foods = this.http.post(url, { query }, options).pipe(
      map((req) => {
        console.log(req);
      })
    );
    return this.foods;
}
```

Comment: the error message also says {message: "child "query" fails because ["query" is required]",…}

Comment: try to replace `this.http.post(url, query, options)` with `this.http.post(url, {query}, options)`.

Comment: uhh now its giving me 401 unauthorized on the console

Comment: did you try `this.http.post(url, {query}, options)` only?

Comment: wait nvm for some reason i think the query wanted to be in only json format so i tested it like that and it worked. Thank you so much

Comment: actually doing {query:"apple"} worked manually but trying to do it dynamically wont work ```{query:`${query}`}```. 
any ideas?

Comment: look this examples https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2019/11/21/angular-http-post-request-examples

Comment: `this.http.post( URL , BODY , OPTIONS )`. the issue in BODY. you sent string instead of  object. so `{query: 'xxxx'}` will work successfully. you can get query as string as argument  then pass it to BODY like `{query: query}` or `{query}`.